# python Vs bash string slicing

Tags: python, quoting, string

My file `a` contains the text,

```
bcd\\\\.
```

With bash, i read the file and print characters from 4th to 8th position as,

```
tmp=$(cat a)
echo "${tmp:3:4}"
```

It prints,

```
\\\\
```

All happy. Now i use python's array slicing to print characters from 4th to 8th position as,

```
>>> f = open('a')
>>> v=f.read()
>>> v[3:7]
```

It prints,

```
'\\\\\\\\'
```

Why does bash and python behave differently when there are backslashes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a matter of how python displays strings.  Observe:

```
>>> f = open('a')
>>> v=f.read()
>>> v[3:7]
'\\\\\\\\'
>>> print v[3:7]
\\\\
```

When displaying `v[3:7]`, the backslashes are escaped.  When printing, `print v[3:7]`, they are not escaped.

#### Other examples

The line in your file should end with a newline character.  In that case, observe:

```
>>> v[-1]
'\n'
>>> print v[-1]


>>>
```

The newline character is displayed as a backslash-n.  It prints as a newline.

The results for tab are similar:

```
>>> s='a\tb'
>>> s
'a\tb'
>>> print s
a       b
```

Comment: It's the difference between `__repr__` and `__str__`, when you print something out, you get the return from the `__str__` function, but when you just have it echoed on the console, you get the `__repr__` return value